# Get the specific element in JAVA String[]

Tags: java

I wish to get the specific element named *Something* in a string within a String[] for JAVA.

My code =

```
String sentence = "AP=Something+example|AS=Explanation";
String[] word = sentence.split("\\|");
for (String w: word){
   System.out.println(w);
}
```

My current output:

```
AP=Something+example
AS=Explanation
```

My expected output should be:

```
Something // the other information I dont want to take. Is there a better and faster way and not too time consuming?
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why don't you just `split("+")`?

Comment: Oh yeah, let me try.

Comment: Nope, I received errors Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '+' near index 0
+
^

Comment: Or rather `String word = sentence.substring(sentence.indexOf('S'), sentence.indexOf('+'));`

Comment: But your above method is only works when the indexOf contains "S" right? What about if my "Something" keeps changing and not always as "Something" but as "Another"?

Comment: Confused - why split on pipe when you want to split on `+`?  Should also be escaped as per `|`

Comment: I received errors when split on +. thats why. I posted the error on the comment

Comment: I solved the errors. May I know how to get the substring after AP?

Comment: Then you need to specify the rules. If you mean "between = and +" then change `sentence.indexOf('S')` to `sentence.indexOf('=')+1`.

Comment: Yes, but did you double backslash it? `sentence.split("\\+")`

Comment: It worked! I will read about this functions used. I learnt something thank you!

Comment: Here's the documentation of the methods used: [`String#substring(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) and [`String#indexOf(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split on plus **not** pipe then change

```
String[] word = sentence.split("\\|");
```

to

```
String[] word = sentence.split("\\+");
```

Comment: Apparently he wants to get rid of `"AP="` also. So that would be something along the lines of `String word = sentence.split("\\+")[0].split("=")[1];`.

Comment: @Gendarme Thanks.  Apparently I did not understand what he wanted.

Comment: The markdown on SO makes it somewhat confusing, as the OP has not put the output inside quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you really want, but:

```
        String sentence = "AP=Something+example|AS=Explanation";
        String[] recs = sentence.split("\\|");
        HashMap<String, String> h = new HashMap<String,String>();
        for (String r : recs) {
            String[] vals = r.split("=");
            h.put(vals[0], vals[1]);
        }
        System.out.println(h.get("AP").split("\\+")[0]);
```

This code is so bad, but look at common idea.

My english so bad too.